# pycsw ebrim response

Tags: metadata, csw, pycsw

Using the same database provided by pycsw for testing (records.db), I notice that the response to the request for **ebrim** output schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<csw:GetRecords xmlns:fgdc="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/csdgm" 
                xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" 
                xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                service="CSW"                    
                version="2.0.2" 
                resultType="results" 
                startPosition="1" 
                maxRecords="5" 
                outputFormat="application/xml" 
                outputSchema="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 
                http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd" 
                xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
    <csw:Query typeNames="csw:Record">
        <csw:ElementSetName>full</csw:ElementSetName>        
    </csw:Query>
</csw:GetRecords>
```

deliver the same number of elements than the request for **apiso** output schema (as expected)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<csw:GetRecords xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" 
                xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
                service="CSW" 
                version="2.0.2" 
                resultType="results" 
                startPosition="1" 
                maxRecords="5" 
                outputFormat="application/xml" 
                outputSchema="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 
                http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
<csw:Query typeNames="gmd:MD_Metadata">
    <csw:ElementSetName>full</csw:ElementSetName>
</csw:Query>
```

but the contents of the **apiso** schema is richer that the one in **ebrim**.

For **ebrim** the response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- pycsw 1.10.0 -->
<csw:GetRecordsResponse xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
                        xmlns:dif="http://gcmd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Aboutus/xml/dif/" 
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
                        xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
                        xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" 
                        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                        xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" 
                        xmlns:fgdc="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/csdgm" 
                        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
                        xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
                        xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" 
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" 
                        xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
                        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                        xmlns:wrs="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0" 
                        version="2.0.2" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
  <csw:SearchStatus timestamp="2014-12-04T14:40:50Z"/>
  <csw:SearchResults nextRecord="6" 
                     numberOfRecordsMatched="41" 
                     numberOfRecordsReturned="5" 
                     recordSchema="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0" 
                     elementSet="full">
    <rim:ExtrinsicObject xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/csw-ebrim.xsd" 
                         id="urn:uuid:19887a8a-f6b0-4a63-ae56-7fba0e17801f" 
                         lid="urn:uuid:19887a8a-f6b0-4a63-ae56-7fba0e17801f" 
                         objectType="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Image" 
                         status="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:StatusType:Submitted">
      <rim:VersionInfo versionName=""/>
    </rim:ExtrinsicObject>
    <rim:ExtrinsicObject xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/csw-ebrim.xsd" 
    ...
    </rim:ExtrinsicObject>
    <rim:ExtrinsicObject xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/csw-ebrim.xsd" 
    ...
    </rim:ExtrinsicObject>
    <rim:ExtrinsicObject xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/csw-ebrim.xsd" 
    ...
    </rim:ExtrinsicObject>
    <rim:ExtrinsicObject xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/wrs/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/ebrim/1.0/csw-ebrim.xsd" 
    ...
    </rim:ExtrinsicObject>    
  </csw:SearchResults>
</csw:GetRecordsResponse>
```

For **apiso** the respose is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- pycsw 1.10.0 -->
<csw:GetRecordsResponse xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
                        xmlns:inspire_common="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/common/1.0" 
                        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
                        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                        xmlns:dct="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
                        xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" 
                        xmlns:apiso="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/apiso/1.0" 
                        xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" 
                        xmlns:dif="http://gcmd.gsfc.nasa.gov/Aboutus/xml/dif/" 
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
                        xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" 
                        xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
                        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
                        xmlns:srv="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/srv" 
                        xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
                        xmlns:fgdc="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/csdgm" 
                        xmlns:inspire_ds="http://inspire.ec.europa.eu/schemas/inspire_ds/1.0" 
                        xmlns:csw="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2" 
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" 
                        xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                        xmlns:sitemap="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
                        version="2.0.2" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw/2.0.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/CSW-discovery.xsd">
  <csw:SearchStatus timestamp="2014-12-04T14:59:32Z"/>
  <csw:SearchResults nextRecord="6" 
                     numberOfRecordsMatched="41" 
                     numberOfRecordsReturned="5" 
                     recordSchema="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" 
                     elementSet="full">
    <gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/apiso/1.0.0/apiso.xsd">
      <gmd:fileIdentifier>
        <gco:CharacterString>urn:uuid:19887a8a-f6b0-4a63-ae56-7fba0e17801f</gco:CharacterString>
      </gmd:fileIdentifier>
      <gmd:language>
        <gco:CharacterString/>
      </gmd:language>
      <gmd:hierarchyLevel>
        <gmd:MD_ScopeCode codeList="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/resources/Codelist/gmxCodelists.xml#MD_ScopeCode" codeListValue="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Image" codeSpace="ISOTC211/19115">http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/Image
      </gmd:MD_ScopeCode>
      </gmd:hierarchyLevel>
      <gmd:contact/>
      <gmd:dateStamp>
        <gco:Date/>
      </gmd:dateStamp>
      <gmd:metadataStandardName>
        <gco:CharacterString>ISO19115</gco:CharacterString>
      </gmd:metadataStandardName>
      <gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
        <gco:CharacterString>2003/Cor.1:2006</gco:CharacterString>
      </gmd:metadataStandardVersion>
      <gmd:identificationInfo>
        <gmd:MD_DataIdentification id="urn:uuid:19887a8a-f6b0-4a63-ae56-7fba0e17801f">
          <gmd:citation>
            <gmd:CI_Citation>
              <gmd:title>
                <gco:CharacterString>Lorem ipsum</gco:CharacterString>
              </gmd:title>
            </gmd:CI_Citation>
          </gmd:citation>
          <gmd:abstract>
            <gco:CharacterString>Quisque lacus diam, placerat mollis, pharetra in, commodo sed, augue. Duis iaculis arcu vel arcu.</gco:CharacterString>
          </gmd:abstract>
          <gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
            <gmd:MD_Keywords>
              <gmd:keyword>
                <gco:CharacterString>Tourism--Greece</gco:CharacterString>
              </gmd:keyword>
            </gmd:MD_Keywords>
          </gmd:descriptiveKeywords>
          <gmd:language>
            <gco:CharacterString/>
          </gmd:language>
        </gmd:MD_DataIdentification>
      </gmd:identificationInfo>
    </gmd:MD_Metadata>
    <gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/apiso/1.0.0/apiso.xsd">
      ...
    </gmd:MD_Metadata>
    <gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/apiso/1.0.0/apiso.xsd">
      ...
    </gmd:MD_Metadata>
    <gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/apiso/1.0.0/apiso.xsd">
      ...
    </gmd:MD_Metadata>
    <gmd:MD_Metadata xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd   http://schemas.opengis.net/csw/2.0.2/profiles/apiso/1.0.0/apiso.xsd">
      ...
    </gmd:MD_Metadata>
  </csw:SearchResults>
</csw:GetRecordsResponse>
```

Do you know why I get difference? I think the contents should be the same, but may with another structure, due the different output schema. In ebrim there is not information from the database.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug.  Filed and fixed at https://github.com/geopython/pycsw/issues/293.